# Skyrim 'Report to Ulfric' completely broken

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I took over whiterun in the civil war.

It told me to report back to ulfric.

I travelled to windhelm. I tried every dialogue option. None were the ones required to complete that objective. The whiterun battle music was still playing and the fast travel point to whiterun has not appeared again.

I ran a command I found online to stop the dumb music but now I've realised that the reason why it was playing is because the game thinks whiterun is still in war mode.

What do I do?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? If so can you please list them? Can you also tell us what command you ran?